# How to work with spinet in visual studio code editor

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

New code editor is good. We need some basic and easy way to work with this editor. Can anyone tell me how to achieve or manipulate some snippets like "html" in code ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editingevolved#_snippets). You can use [Emmet abbreviations](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) to insert snippets. For example, in a html file, type "!" + TAB to create the HTML5 base structure.